# Invalid Signature - Creating Flickr Photoset

Tags: api, oauth, clojure, flickr

I'am trying now for hours to get a valid api call for flickr. The following link is build by my clojure program:

> "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.create&oauth_signature=
>   {sig}&oauth_token={token}&oauth_consumer_key={key}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp={time}&oauth_nonce={nonce}&oauth_version=1.0&title={title}&primary_photo_id={photoid}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"

And that is the message the browser returns:

> oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=GET&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Frest%2F&format%3Djson%26method%3Dflickr.photosets.create%26nojsoncallback%3D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3D23XXXXXXXXXXX6e46a05ae55c4%26oauth_nonce%3De6u52XXXXXXXXXpphqner4e0j%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D13XXXXX06%26oauth_token%3D721XXXXXXXX503-356bXXXXXXXf66e%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26primary_photo_id%3D12345678%26title%3Dphotoset-title

Calls with method "flickr.photosets.getPhotos" and "flickr.photosets.getList" are working.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does the oauth_token for this request have write permissions? (e.g perms=write in the original authentication url)

Answer (score 0):

The signature is invalid. The result you're getting is the correct string you should have sent. Please post the signature you sent and the signature it posted back. You need to compare them and see what's wrong with the one you sent.

Comment: The signature i sent is the same signature it posted back. But with status 401...

Comment: I had my share of bugs with the Flickr API, and I learned that if the response is a debug base-string then something is off with the signature. Please do put the base string used for the call with the base string returned.